# How to expose custom metrics from HTTP response

Tags: web-scraping, prometheus, metrics, exporter, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Good morning, I need some help solving the following problem:

The solution I want to monitor does not provide ready-made metrics for Prometheus, but it does provide a whole series of APIs. For example, at the endpoint [www.example.com/api/license](http://www.example.com/api/license), the HTTP response contains a value indicating the current credit consumption for that particular licence. How can we go about scraping this value from the HTTP response and expose it as a metric? Blackbox exporter be useful in this regard? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance

I tried to use blackbox, but I have not been able to scrape the result.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot parse data from response and expose it as a metric through blackbox. You can simply fail scrape if left-over license is too low with use of `fail_if_body_not_matches_regexp`. If this is not enough - consider using some other exporter. You can use textfile in node_exporter and custom script for scraping and parsing. Or something called exporter_exporter, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60137349).

Comment: yes thank you very much